# Integration of a real valued function on complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$f$ is continuous, bounded, $f(z)\geq 0$.

Can we claim that the following integration

$$\int_{C_R}f(z)dz$$

is equal to zero?  ($C_R$ is a circle centered on 0, with radius R )

and what if $R\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: No. What's is $\;C_R\;$ and what exactly is $\;f\;$ ?

Comment: What is $C_R$? Is the circumference of a circle?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but not necessary.

For example, if $f(z)=1$, then $\int_{C_R}f(z)\,dz=0$.

If $$
f(z)=\min\left\{\max\Big\{\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}+2,1\Big\},4\right\}
$$ 
then, $f$ continuous in $\mathbb R^2$, $\,\,f\ge 1,$ and
$\int_{C_R}f(z)\,dz=-2\pi$.

Comment: if $f(z)=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$, then $f\geq 0$ does not meet?

Comment: The second example is also not continuous at every point: Not at $z=(x,y)=(0,0)$

Comment: @Jerry See my corrected version.

Comment: What if $R \rightarrow \infty$? Is there some function when $R \rightarrow \infty$ the integral not equal to 0?

Answer (score 0):

The function $1$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$, and
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{C_R}1\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\int_{C_R}1\,\mathrm{d}(x+iy)\\
&=\int_{C_R}\,\mathrm{d}x+i\int_{C_R}\,\mathrm{d}y\\[6pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$

---

**One Example**

The function
$$
f(z)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
0&\text{if }y\lt-R\\
y+R&\text{if }\left|y\right|\le R\\
2R&\text{if }y\gt R
\end{array}\right.
$$
is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$, and if $C_R$ circles its interior counter-clockwise,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{C_R}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\int_{C_R}(y+R)\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\int_{C_R}(y+R)\,\mathrm{d}(x+iy)\\
&=\int_{C_R}(y+R)\,\mathrm{d}x+i\int_{C_R}(y+R)\,\mathrm{d}y\\[3pt]
&=\int_{C_R}y\,\mathrm{d}x+i\int_{C_R}y\,\mathrm{d}y\\[3pt]
&=-\text{Area}(C_R)+0\\[9pt]
&=-\pi R^2
\end{align}
$$

---

**Second Example**

The function
$$
f(z)=1+\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}
$$
is positive, bounded, and continuous on $\mathbb{C}$. If $C_R$ circles its interior counter-clockwise,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{C_R}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\int_{C_R}\left(1+\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\int_{C_R}\left(1+\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}(x+iy)\\
&=\int_{C_R}\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x+i\int_{C_R}\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_{C_R}\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$
which, according to [Green's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_theorem), is the integral of $-\left(1+y^2\right)^{-3/2}$ over the interior of $C_R$, which is clearly negative.

Comment: y=Im(z) is not bounded

Comment: So change it outside a circle of radius $R$ so it is if that bothers you.

Comment: y is also not always greater than 0

Comment: Add $R$ inside the circle of radius $R$. Okay, I will add these to my answer,

Comment: Answer modified. Nothing has really changed with the idea of the example.

Comment: Added another example where the integral is not $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f\in C^1$, and denote by $D_R$ the disc of radius $R$ centered at $0$. Then Green's theorem says that
$$\int_{C_R} f(z)\>dz=\int_{\partial D_R}f(x,y)\>(dx+i dy)=\int_{D_R}(i f_x- f_y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)\ .$$
As $f$ is assumed real it follows that your integral vanishes iff
$$\int_{D_R} f_x\>{\rm d}(x,y)=\int_{D_R} f_y\>{\rm d}(x,y)=0\ .$$